# Drupal 7 template_preprocess_block

Tags: theming, blocks, 7

I am trying to alter content of the system main block but only on the front page. I have added template_preprocess_block() in the template.php file, but is_front is FALSE even though I am on the front page of the site?

I use the Context module to control blocks, but the main block is the only one I have added using /admin/structure/block not Context.

*Update*
I have also tested hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter() but is_front is not passed to this function.

*Update*
Even though I disable the Main page content block front the Content region, I still see a node on the front page, publishing options set to published, promoted to front.
Doing this on a fresh install locally.

Enabling the Main page content block and setting "All pages except those listed" to  doesn't change anything - still looking at my node.

Answer (score 1):

Use function `drupal_is_front_page()`.

Answer (score 0):

simplest and most straightforward solution:
Create two versions of that block and from this textarea select where the block should be

[image]

then do the appropriate configuration.

Comment: yeah, that could be an option

Comment: weird but remoning the main block from the content region has no effect. I still see content on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this, even if the conditions aren't exactly the same:

```
<?php
    // works with paths like 'home' too, as well as 'node/2'
    $is_front_page = ($_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node') || drupal_get_path_alias(current_path()) == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
?>
```

borrowed from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1503146)